# True random is not true random I am really confused

Tags: c#, random

Alright I tested the way below.

Generated `x` times random numbers between `0~x` and then checked the ones that were not generated.

I would assume that it would be very close to 100%. What I mean is all numbers between `0~x` are generated.

But results are shocking. About **36%** of the numbers are **missing**.

Is my random function not really random?

Here below my random class:

```
private static Random seedGenerator = new Random();

private static ThreadLocal<Random> random = 
    new ThreadLocal<Random>(SeededRandomFactory);

private static Random SeededRandomFactory()
{
    lock (seedGenerator)
        return new Random(seedGenerator.Next());
}

public static int GenerateRandomValueMin(int irRandValRange, int irMinValue)
{
    return random.Value.Next(irMinValue, irMinValue + irRandValRange);
}
```

Here the below results:

```
Between 0-10, missing numbers count: 4, percent: 40%
Between 0-100, missing numbers count: 36, percent: 36%
Between 0-1000, missing numbers count: 369, percent: 36,9%
Between 0-10000, missing numbers count: 3674, percent: 36,74%
Between 0-100000, missing numbers count: 36583, percent: 36,58%
Between 0-1000000, missing numbers count: 367900, percent: 36,79%
Between 0-10000000, missing numbers count: 3678122, percent: 36,78%
Between 0-100000000, missing numbers count: 36797477, percent: 36,8%
```

Here the code how I check:

```
File.WriteAllText("results.txt", "");

int irFirst = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    HashSet<int> hsGenerated = new HashSet<int>();

    for (int k = 0; k < irFirst; k++)
    {
        hsGenerated.Add(GenerateRandomValue.GenerateRandomValueMin(irFirst, 0));
    }

    int irNotFound = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < irFirst; k++)
    {
        if (hsGenerated.Contains(k) == false)
            irNotFound++;
    }

    string srSonuc = 
        string.Format(
            "Between 0-{0}, missing numbers count: {1}, percent: {2}%", 
            irFirst, irNotFound,
            Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(irNotFound)/Convert.ToDouble(irFirst))*100.0, 2).ToString()
            );

    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("sonuclar.txt"))
    {
        w.WriteLine(srSonuc);
    }

    irFirst = irFirst * 10;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code you're using to measure the missing numbers?

Comment: @svick sure added whole code

Comment: Is "random" for you an equally distributed value output?

Comment: @Patrick yes. Isnt that true random ?

Comment: If it were "close to 100%", the last value you generate would be very predictable. Predictable is the opposite of random. So: Think again ;-)

Comment: How many times are you calling `Generate`? If you're only generating ten numbers for the 0-10 block, then getting 1 of each number is not expected. An even distribution is only expected *on average*, i.e. for a very large sample size.

Comment: Well, no.. Only if you measure an "endless" number of times

Comment: @Patrick You mean [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29)? Because that's exactly what I'd expect.

Comment: The "answer" to this question at the moment is that you're thinking of random incorrect. Your measurements is not on a sufficiently large sample size, as @Jason explained. Would you mind elaborating on what kind of answer you are looking for?

Comment: Patrick if this was true random, wouldnt we expect all of the numbers generated ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: No, as Jason wrote, it's only expected on average. If you throw a die 6 times you normally don't get each of the six values, even though it's a "function" with uniform distribution.

Comment: What determines average ? Isn't random mean all chances are equal ?

Comment: Random does not mean all chances are equal. Uniform means that.

Comment: If you were to roll a dice six times, would you *really* expect to not roll the same number twice? Actually, go try it. Roll a dice 6 times and note if you got any duplicates. Try it a few times. How often do you get duplicates?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan are there any way to generate true uniform random number ? is that possible . because this way it is really bad.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: "True random" as you define it would be to have a list with each of the values between 0 and x, and remove each value as you select it.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: What you want isn't random numbers. You want a set of numbers presented in a random order - which is a different thing. You can get the effect by randomly shuffling an array of the numbers you want.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG You need to slow down and read the answers and think a little. The problem lies in your head. Your expectation is not correct. Your results are fine. If you really do want every possible value to appear exactly once, use Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: No i don't want exactly one time only. I would expect close to 99% percent instead of 64%. Or at least 90%+ percent. So you say this isn't possible with current technology ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG This has nothing to do with technology. No technology, current, or future, will change the underlying math.

Comment: There's no technology involved. If you sample with replacement, numbers in the range 0..N-1, and sample N numbers, then you expect to miss 36% of the values. That's a mathematical truth. If you want something else you'll need to code something else.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that is what i am saying. Since this is possible, you accept this as a fact. But if it was a true true random, that would be 100%. If technology were better that would be over 90%+. Because if you close your eyes and select a number from bag of words, you would give each word equal chance. But it is clear here that, in computer this is not the case.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Yep, with current dice technology, a D20 will not perform as you expect. Damn those dice and their crappy technology! Because you clearly expect that if you roll a D20 20 times, you'll see all the numbers from 1-20, unless there's something wrong with the "technology".

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Read the penultimate paragraph of my answer. You are asserting that a coin has a memory. If you toss a tails, then the next one is heads.

Comment: Ok tell me that isn't what i expect from random is more accurate or not ? Lets not think about the facts. I mean what we have. But i would expect from random that it will be equally distributed. Giving each time equal chance. But i got my answer for this question :)

Comment: +1 for the introduction of "true true random" as a synonym for predictability.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your testing method is off.

You draw x times a number between 0 and x. The probability that a specific number is **not** drawn is:

[image: ((x-1)/x)^x]

As x approaches infinity, p will go towards 1/e (or approx. 36.7879441%) And this is the number you are seeing in your results.
Also, as x approaches infinity, you will observe this probability as outcome of your sample (Law of large numbers)

This has to do with probability. When you have a bowl with a red and a white marble. And you take one, put it back an take another one you *cannot* guarantee that you see both. You could take the red one twice. You are doing the same thing with more objects.

---

To elaborate on true true randomness:

> I would expect close to 99% percent instead of 64%. Or at least 90%+ percent. So you say this isn't possible with current technology

That is simple. Thanks to modern math, technology and my super powers I can tell you how to do that: You need more draws than numbers to choose from. The formula becomes:

[image: more math]

where n is you desired percentage of missing numbers. For example if you are willing to accept 5% numbers missing, you must draw three times as many random numbers. For a 1% chance, you need to iterate 4.6 times the maximum number.

This math assumes a perfectly uniform random number generation.

Comment: yes. i understood the reason. reason is computers are based on math so still not able to generate true random

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: It is _not_ because computers don't generate truly random numbers. Even if you throw a perfect dice 6 times, you are not guaranteed to get 6 different numbers. It is an inherent behaviour in randomness.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: It's nothing to do with not-truely-random numbers. You will get just the same effect with dice!

Comment: There is no possible way you can roll dice truely randomly :) If you pick a letter from bag of letters, you would give each letter equal chance. Am i incorrect? But it is clear here not the same. Even that your pick would not be true random.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Yes, but if you have n letters, you always put the drawn letter back in the bag and you draw n times, it's unlikely that you're going to get all letters. If you don't want to put the letter back in the bag, then you need to use a different algorithm.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: But you are doing different things! In one case you're rolling dice multiple times, where the outcome of each dice roll has no effect on the next. In the other case, you are removing items from a bag - where the outcome of each removal certainly DOES affect the next one - because once you're removed an item from the bag, it's never going to be drawn again. But if you roll a 6, you can roll another next time. You are expecting the dice rolling to behave like removing things from a bag - but it should be trivially obvious that they are not the same!

Comment: are there any function in c# that provides the effect you meantion ? any randomization thing ? so with 1 iteration i will obtain what i want :)

Comment: No. If you roll a (perfect) six-sided dice four times, the probability of getting every number (1 to 6) once is zero. At six rolls, it is a slim 1.5% chance. Roll it 8 times and you will get a 11.4% chance. Ten times, 27% chance. Finally at 36 rolls there is a 99.15% chance that every number appears at least once. This probability increases with the number of rolls, not the randomness of the dice.

Comment: @Das I don't think Monster can understand, or perhaps just doesn't want to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Your results are exactly what is to be expected from a uniform distribution where you sample with replacement.

Consider the simplest possible example. You have a coin and toss it twice. So we assume that we are sampling from a uniform discrete distribution.

The possible outcomes, which occur with equal probability of 0.25 are:

```
TT
TH
HT
HH
```

As you can see, only two of the four outcomes have both heads and tails.

This is known as sampling with replacement. So, once we have sampled a tails, then we "put it back in the bag", and it could come out again on the next sample.

Now suppose we sample without replacement. In that case there are two possible outcomes:

```
TH
HT
```

And as you see, each possible value appears exactly once.

Essentially your expectation for the results is not correct. As another example, suppose you toss a coin and it comes down tails. What do you expect will happen on the next toss. You are arguing that the coin must now come down heads. But that is clearly nonsense.

---

If you did want to sample without replacement, and it's not clear that's really what you want, then you do so with the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: so you are saying 36% is expected ? well i would expect from true random close to 100% distribution

Comment: I see. Computers are nothing but math so it seems like true random is still not possible

Comment: The code in your question samples with replacement from the uniform distribution. Your expectations are simply incorrect. Read my updated answer again. Particularly the final example in the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: No i believe my expectation is correct. If you toss a coin 1000 times, i would expect close to 500 times down and close to 500 times up sides came.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: You don't see... His example is nothing to do with computers and everything to do with the real world! Your code isn't doing the equivalent of tossing a coin 1000 times. It's more like tossing a coin twice and expecting it to show one head and one tail.

Comment: You are not tossing a coin 1000 times. You are rolling a fair 1000 sided dice 1000 times. Your expectations are undeniably wrong.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG But that's not what you're doing. You're tossing a two-sided coin twice, or 6-sided die 6 times.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I don't understand why you downvoted my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want 100 million unique random number you could do something like this:

Now using Fisher-Yates suffle algorithm:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>(100000000);
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Capacity; i++)
{
    int rnd = random.Next(numbers.Count + 1);
    if (rnd == numbers.Count)
        numbers.Add(i);
    else
    {
        numbers.Add(numbers[rnd]);
        numbers[rnd] = i;
    }
}
```

By the way you could calculate irNotFound much faster:

```
int irNotFound = irFirst - hsGenerated.Count;
```

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: thanks but that is what i meant. I am generating a new random number but see that it is not truly distributed.

Comment: This code is generating a not-so-random *permutation*. "uniform distribution" is the wrong term here; a uniform distribution wouldn't enforce that each number occurs exactly once.

Comment: Well i will try your solution. If it is better that will improve my function for certain thing ^^

Comment: "not-so-random" because this implementation is broken and doesn't give a uniform distribution over all possible permutations. Look up "fisher-yates-shuffle" for the correct solution.

Comment: @Casperah You don't use uniform accurately at all. The code in the question samples uniformly. The code in this answer does nothing very useful.

Comment: That's quite a novel Fisher-Yates implementation. Where did you get it from?

Comment: THe Fisher-Yates implementation is taken from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle